# Bochner integrable function is a.e. non-negative, if Bochner integral is non-negative on all sets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hahn-banach-theorem, bochner-spaces

I know that the Hahn-Banach Theorem, implies the following statement for Banach-space valued functions:

Let $(X, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite complete measure space, and $(E, |\cdot|_E)$ a (separable) Banach space. Assume $f:X \to E$ is $\mu$-integrable such that
$$
\int_A f \mathrm d \mu = 0 \quad \forall A \in \mathcal F.
$$
Then it follows that $f=0$ $\mu$-a.e.

If we now additionally assume that there exists an ordering on $E$, such that:

$$
x \le y \implies c \ge 0 \implies c \cdot x \le c \cdot y
$$
$$
c \le d \implies x \ge 0 \implies c \cdot x \le d \cdot x
$$
for $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y \in E$

Does this imply the following analogous statement:

$$
\int_A f \mathrm d \mu \ge 0 \quad \forall A \in \mathcal F. \implies f \ge 0 \quad \mu\text{-a.e.}
$$

I am a beginner in this area, so I lack the intuition (although I feel like it should probably be true). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The answer turns out to be yes. If anyone is interested I will provide details in an answer.